# Laravel - Select input not keeping old value

Tags: php, laravel, homestead, laravelcollective

I have a piece of code:

```
{!! Form::select('option_employee_review', old('option_employee_review', $employeeReviews), $employeeReviews, ['id' => 'option_employee_review', 'class' => 'form-control ']); !!}
```

It saves the value to the database correct. When i go to edit the item again the select input does not keep the old value that's in the database. How do i make it so that the select input does keep its old value.

`$employeeReviews`:

```
[
  2843 => "Medewerker review 1"
  2849 => "Medewerker review 2"
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not using your syntax, but something like this will do I think.

```html
<option value="{{$channel->id}}" {{ (old("channel_id") == $channel->id ? "selected" : "" ) }}>{{$channel->title}}</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Second parameter to select function must be array of options.

Try changing it like this

`{!! Form::select('option_employee_review', $employeeReviews, old('option_employee_review', $employeeReviews), ['id' => 'option_employee_review', 'class' => 'form-control ']); !!}`

Or based on your parent object let's say `employee` you can try

```
{!! Form::select('option_employee_review', $employeeReviews, $employee->option_employee_review, ['id' => 'option_employee_review', 'class' => 'form-control ']); !!}
```